# Non of the webdriverio methods work to wait until an element is shown using Appium & WebDriverIO (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, webdriver, appium, webdriver-io

I am trying to write a test case use in JavaScript with webdriverio (using appium server) for a native android app.

My test case requires me to log in the app, and after logging (which takes 3-4 seconds) I should click a button (element). I tried all of the WebDriverIO APIs like waitForDisplayed, isDisplayed(), non of them work, most the time the error message is that :

```
  TypeError: client.element(...).waitForDisplayed is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test-auto-obi-copy.js:142:14)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:130:23)
```

Here is the WebDriverIO Documentation for waitForDisplayed https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/waitForClickable.html

My code looks like this:

```
it("should press the profile button", function () {
    return client
    .element('android=new UiSelector().resourceId("com.example.dev:id/nav_graph_profile")')
    .waitForDisplayed(undefined, true)
    .click('android=new UiSelector().resourceId("com.example.dev:id/nav_graph_profile")')
    .then( function() {
        //whatever
    })
})
```

The login test completes succesfully, but after the LOG-IN button is pressed I want to make my test suite "sleep" until the next page loads, to achieve this I was trying to wait until this particular Profile button (element) becomes available, but it seems impossible to wait for it.

Can anyone suggest me what to do in this case, how can I wait?

Comment: What version of WebDriverIO are you running?

Comment: @Shiny "webdriverio": ^4.6.1

Comment: Then try `.waitForVisible` instead - `waitForDisplayed` is the name of the method in v5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebDriverIO changed the names of some of their functions when moving from v4 -> v5 `.waitForDisplayed()` was one of them, [as seen in the changelogs](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v500-2018-12-20).

- WebdriverIO v4 -> `.waitForVisible()`
- WebdriverIO v5 -> `.waitForDisplayed()`

There's a fair few functions that changed names slightly, so it's worth a look - Additionally, the Docs for v4 still exist though are a little harder to search - [Here is the entry for `.waitForVisible()`](http://v4.webdriver.io/api/utility/waitForVisible.html)

Also, by passing `undefined` as the first parameter, your delay will only wait for the default `500ms`. You'll probably want something like this instead

```js
.waitForDisplayed(5000, true)
```

Comment: I am trying with v4 waitForVisible() now, the function is recognised as you mentioned, it is waiting after the log in is pressed, and then the home page is shown, however it throws an error 'Cannot read property 'selector' of undefined at elements() - isVisible.js at isVisible() - waitForVisible.js', do you have any idea what might cause it and how to resolve?

Comment: I think on v4 you'll have to do something like `browser.click('android=new UiSelector().resourceId("com.example.dev:id/nav_graph_profile")')`, rather than chaining - if you read the v4 docs you'll see how it differs in structure then v5, where you can call the `.click` method on the selector itself

Comment: Thank you a lot but can I ask one more questions because I have a confusion, I migrated to API v5 now, and I am using async functions to it(2). I am creating a unique variable every time like `let button1 = await client.$('selector'); button1.click()`, however they are not being executed in order, for example in code I am sending values to two fields and the clicking the button, but the button is being clicked before the fields are filled. I am awaiting each selector and applying the action one by one, but the execution of the webdriver commands it is not on the same order (looked at the log)?

Comment: Here is the complete `it` method (https://repl.it/repls/UnimportantInternalError)

Comment: Afraid I'm not sure for that particular question - I think it might be related to the `addValue` taking some extra time to write the content, but that time not being counted for the async; however, you're probably going to have to research that one yourself and perhaps start a new question for that one